# Python : Matching a custom date format in a string

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a string like this:

```
>>> string = "bla_bla-whatever_2018.02.09_11.34.09_more_bla-123"
```

I need to extract the date `2018.02.09_11.34.09` from it. It will always be in this format.

So I tried:

```
>>> match = re.search(r'\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}_\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}', string)
```

It correctly extracts out the date from that string:

```
>>> match.group()
'2018.02.09_11.34.09'
```

But then when I try to create a datetime object from this string, it doesn't work:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y.%m.%d_%H.%I.%S')
ValueError: time data '2018.02.09_11.34.09' does not match format '%Y.%m.%d_%H.%I.%S'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to replace the format specifier `%I` with `%M`, for minutes:

```
%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S
```

`%I` denotes hour in 12-hour format so from *(0)1..12*, whereas based on your example, you have *34* as the value, which presumably is in minutes (`%M`).

Comment: I can't believe I did not see that mistake. Thanks and sorry for have wasted your time!

Comment: @shikhanshu It happens :)